# How to send information from one class to another using rxswift?

Tags: ios, swift

How to send information from one class A to another class B using rxswift ? In iOS . for example I want to send my class Account.

Maybe rxswift is not for delegates or sending information at all.
https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/7pxt4h/rxswift_vs_delegation_which_is_better/

```
class Account
{
   var  myId = 0
   var  Name = "name"

   init (myId inputMyId:Int , Name inputName: String)
   {
       myId = inputMyId
       Name = inputName
   }
}  

class B
{
   var myAccount : Account
   func receive()
   {
   // here  self.myAccount should be replaced with myA.myAccount 
   // where myA is object of class A
   }
}



class A
{
   var myAccount : Account
   func send()
   {
   // here  myB.myAccount should be replaced with self.myAccount
   // where myB is object of class B
   }
}
```

## solution 1

create class C that will make observables equal from A and B

```
class SimpleC
{
    func makeAB()
    {
        var theB : SimpleB = SimpleB()
        var theA : SimpleA = SimpleA()
        theA.valueAccount = theB.valueAccount
        theB.receive()
        theA.send()
    }
}


class SimpleA
{
    var myAccount : Account = Account(myId : 0, Name : "")
    var valueAccount = PublishSubject<Account>()
    var myB : SimpleB?
    func send()
    {
        // here  myB.myAccount should be replaced with self.myAccount
        // where myB is object of class B

        self.myAccount = Account(myId : 1, Name : "MicrosoftTest5")
        self.valueAccount.onNext(self.myAccount)

        self.myAccount = Account(myId : 2, Name : "bestWorkTest5")
        self.valueAccount.onNext(self.myAccount)

    }
}


class SimpleB
{
    var myAccount : Account = Account(myId : 0, Name : "")
    var valueAccount = PublishSubject<Account>()
    let disposer = DisposeBag()
    func receive()
    {
        // here  self.myAccount should be replaced with myA.myAccount
        // where myA is object of class A
        valueAccount.subscribe(onNext: { (newValue) in
            print("SimpleB subscribe")
            self.myAccount = newValue
            var theString = "Account{" + "\(self.myAccount.myId)"
            theString =  theString + "} {"
            theString =  theString + "\(self.myAccount.Name)" + "}"
            print(theString)
        }).addDisposableTo(disposer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question in hope to cover two scinarios -

**Case 1: passing data while object creation (I can create and wrap it in variables, and pass along), this is same as vanilla swift**

> This holds true in cases of pushing/ presenting as well

```
class Account
{
    var  myId = Variable(0)
    var  name = Variable("")

    init (myId inputMyId:Int , Name inputName: String)
    {
        myId.value = inputMyId
        name.value = inputName
    }

    func passDataAnotherAccount() {
        let anotherAccount = AnotherAccount(id: myId, name: name)
        anotherAccount.makeChangesToVars()
    }

}


class AnotherAccount {

    var classListenerOfMyId = Variable(0)
    var classListenerOfMyName = Variable("name")

    init(id: Variable<Int>, name: Variable<String>) {
        self.classListenerOfMyId = id
        self.classListenerOfMyName = name
    }


    func makeChangesToVars() {
        self.classListenerOfMyId.value = self.classListenerOfMyId.value + 1
        self.classListenerOfMyName.value = Date().description
    }

}
```

**case 2 (Alternative approach to DELEGATION and callbacks)**

> lets say you want to know about changes from class AnotherAccount in previous class, you can make use of **OBSERVABLES** in that case

change the method  from class Account to this

```
func passDataAnotherAccount() {
    let anotherAccount = AnotherAccount(id: myId, name: name)
    anotherAccount.makeChangesToVars()

    // this will observe changes from AnotherAccount class
    // we just created above in my current class,
    // i.e. Account class
    anotherAccount.classListenerOfMyId.asObservable().subscribe(onNext:{[weak self] valueChange in
        print(valueChange)
    }).disposed(by: DisposeBag())
    anotherAccount.classListenerOfMyName.asObservable().subscribe(onNext:{[weak self] valueChange in
        print(valueChange)
    }).disposed(by: DisposeBag())
}
```

for handling delegations/callbacks you need to observe the changes by subscribing to the underlying Variables/Subjects/Observable.

**Points to Note**

> 1. Please use single dispose bag for one class, unlike me, i have disposed using DisposeBag() itself.
> 2. Read More about replacing delegates in RxSwift with Observables (this will be helpful)